# How to have a form PLUS button controls outside the form in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, forms, asp.net-4.0

I have a form and I want some controls to work outside the form.
When I have a form on the page, and a button outside the form, the button doesn't work!?

Here is my code :

```
 <form method="post" action="default.aspx">
    <asp:TextBox ID="leko" runat="server" />

        <asp:Button ID="sub" onclick="sub" runat="server" />

    </form>

            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Tweetline" 
            onclick="Button2_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
```

And the action "Button2_click" doesn't work since the form is here.
Why that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As It is not possible to have multiple Form tag and Server side control can not be outside of form control,
Use `ICallBack` interface in your default.aspx.
Using this you can have your normal button (e.g. no asp:Button instead use <input type="button">).
for more detail refer following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with webforms - the way they work is by having a *single* server side form and all controls live in it.

You *can* have additional normal forms (that is without `runat="server"`, but these cannot be used with server side controls.

If you want better control over your HTML, take a look at [ASP.NET/MVC](http://asp.net/mvc).